# Problem with a SQL SELECT Query

Tags: sql

I have a table GAMES with this information:

```
- Id_Game (int)
- Id_Referee1 (int)
- Id_Referee2 (int)
```

These are some rows:

```
ID_GAME    ID_REFEREE1    ID_REFEREE2
1          1000           728
2          1004           813
3          728            1004
4          1004           1000
```

I want to have a list with the number of games that a referee has officiated, doesn't matter if as a Referee1 or Referee2. In this case, I would like to receive this list order by number of games DESC.

```
REFEREE    NUMBER OF GAMES
1004       3
728        2
1000       2
813        1
```

Which would be the SQL query? I have no idea of how to join fields Id_Referee1 and Id_Referee2...

THANKS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think:

```
select referee, count(*) from (
    select id_game, id_referee1 as referee
    from games
    union
    select id_game, id_referee2 as referee
    from games
)
group by referee
```

Comment: you are assuming id_game is unique - which of course it probably is but @Arturo doesn't specify

Comment: @JackPDouglas You're right, but you are assuming that referee1 != referee2 - which he also didn't specify ;)

Comment: Thank you both, I am testing but it seems OK. Of course Id_game is unique and referee1 != referee2 in the same row. THANKS. I will tell you in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

assuming id_referee1!=id_referee2 for all possible rows (probably using a check constraint):

```
select referee, count(*) as number_of_games 
from( select id_referee1 as referee from games 
      union all 
      select id_referee2 from games )
group by referee
order by count(*) desc;
```

if you don't want to make that assumption:

```
select referee, count(*) as number_of_games 
from( select id_referee1 as referee from games 
      union all 
      select id_referee2 
      from games 
      where id_referee1 is null or id_referee1!=id_referee2 )
group by referee
order by count(*) desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID_REFEREE1, count( * ) as no_of_games
FROM games
GROUP BY ID_REFEREE1
ORDER BY 2
```

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

I think something is wrong because I get an error with this query:

```
SELECT Referee, count(*) FROM 
(
  (SELECT Id_Game, Id_Referee1 as Referee FROM Games) 
  UNION ALL 
  (SELECT Id_Game, Id_Referee2 as Referee FROM Games)
) GROUP BY Referee
```

Can you see what is wrong? THANKS

Comment: In fact, the error I get is "#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias". Any help?

Comment: Some RDBMSs (eg MySQL, postgres) insist on an alias for each subquery, so `select * from (select * from games)` throw an error but `select * from (select * from games) as g` is fine.